# Pandas resampling skips first date of timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

Given:

```
foo = pd.Series(index=pd.bdate_range(datetime.date(2000,1,1),datetime.date(2001,1,1)))
foo.resample("BMS")
foo.resample("BMS").resample("B")
```

The first resample starts at 2000-01-03 and the second resample starts at 2000-01-04

Is this a bug or am I missing a conceptual understanding of how resampling works?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot reproduce in pandas 0.8.0, both timeseries start with 2000-01-03.

Comment: I can reproduce it on 0.10.1, it seems like it's probably a bug... good find.

Comment: added as [issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2753)...

Answer (score 1):

pandas tries to infer the "closed" and "label" parameter values so that the default resampling behavior is correct. This is a bug in inferring those values for upsampling. We'll fix for the next release. Thanks for the bug report.

As a workaround, do foo.resample("BMS").resample("B", closed="right", label="right")